# Orthogonality - Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $\vec{x}$,$\vec{y}$ be two non zero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $\mathbb{R}\cdot\vec{y}$ the subspace spanned by $\vec{y}$. Show that the orthogonal projection of $\vec{x}$ onto $\mathbb{R}\cdot\vec{y}$ is the vector of closest distance to $\vec{x}$ belonging to 
$\mathbb{R}\cdot\vec{y}$. Show last statement by the following two ways:

a) Minimizing the square distance function $f(t) = \vert\vert \vec{x} − t\vec{y}\vert\vert ^{2}$

b) Using that for any subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\vec{x}\in W$ and 
$\vec{y}\in W^{\perp}$. we have

$$\vert\vert \vec{x} + \vec{y}\vert\vert^{2} = \vert\vert x\vert\vert^2 + \vert\vert y\vert\vert^2$$

U better thank me MA 351 peeps :p

Comment: What do you mean by the notation R⃗y? Is this supposed to be the subspace generated by $y$?

Comment: I guess the only thing that makes sense, $\mathbb{R}·y$, however this is really ill written, it is more difficult to understand the question than actually solve the exercise

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The question has been edited.

Comment: Suggestion for part (a): write $\|x - ty\|^2 = \langle x-ty, x-ty\rangle = \langle x,x \rangle + \langle -ty, x \rangle + \langle x, -ty \rangle + \langle -ty, -ty \rangle$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the inner (dot) product. Simplify the expressions on the RHS to get a quadratic in $t$ which you can then minimize straightforwardly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Minimize $f(t) = ({\bf x} - t{\bf y})^2$ by expanding it out: $f(t) = {\bf x}^2 - 2t({\bf x}\cdot {\bf y}) + t^2 {\bf y}^2$.

Differentiate with respect to $t$:
$$
f'(t) = 2t{\bf y}^2 - 2{\bf x}\cdot {\bf y}
$$
and minimize by setting $f'(t) = 0$: 
$$
2t{\bf y}^2 - 2{\bf x}\cdot {\bf y} = 0
$$ 
$$
2t{\bf y}^2 = 2{\bf x}\cdot {\bf y}
$$
$$
t = \frac{{\bf x}\cdot {\bf y}}{{\bf y}^2}
$$

(b) Let $u{\bf y}$ be the orthogonal projection of ${\bf x}$ onto $\langle {\bf y} \rangle$. $({\bf x}-u{\bf y}) \in \langle {\bf y}\rangle^\bot$
$$
{\bf x}^2 = [({\bf x}-u{\bf y}) + u{\bf y}]^2 = ({\bf x}-u{\bf y})^2 + u^2 {\bf y}^2
$$
$$
{\bf x}^2 = {\bf x}^2 - 2u({\bf x} \cdot {\bf y})+2u^2{\bf y}^2
$$
$$
u^2 {\bf y}^2 = u({\bf x} \cdot {\bf y})
$$
$$
u = \frac{{\bf x}\cdot {\bf y}}{{\bf y}^2}
$$
But this is just the formula we got for $t$ above.

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin :) it really helps